# Conditional Expectation Property with Tower Property

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, conditional-expectation

I am having some problems showing the equality below:

Let $Y \in L_2(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ and $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{A}$. Show that for $\mathcal{G} \subset \mathcal{F}$:

$$
\mathbb{E}((Y - \mathbb{E}(Y \vert \mathcal{G}))^2) + \mathbb{E}((\mathbb{E}(Y\vert \mathcal{G}) - \mathbb{E}(Y\vert \mathcal{F}))^2)= \mathbb{E}((Y - \mathbb{E}(Y \vert \mathcal{F}))^2)
$$

I tried the tower property but the whole thing got very messy instantly. So I hope anyone has a good approach on this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Ex}{\mathbb{E}}$
$\newcommand{\F}{\mathcal{F}}$
$\newcommand{\G}{\mathcal{G}}$
The easiest way is by "adding zero":

$$\begin{align*}
&\Ex [(Y - \Ex(Y | \F))^2] \\
&= \Ex [(Y - \Ex (Y | \G) + \Ex (Y|\G) -\Ex(Y | \F))^2] \\
&= \Ex [(Y - \Ex (Y| \G))^2] + \Ex [(\Ex (Y|\G ) - \Ex (Y| \F))^2] - 2 \Ex [(Y - \Ex (Y| \G))(\Ex (Y|\G ) - \Ex (Y| \F))]
\end{align*}$$

By using the tower property, and "pulling out what is known" we then get:

$$\begin{align*}
\Ex [(Y - \Ex (Y| \G))(\Ex (Y|\G ) - \Ex (Y| \F))] &= \Ex [ \Ex [(Y - \Ex (Y| \G))(\Ex (Y|\G ) - \Ex (Y| \F)) | \F] ] \\
&= (\Ex (Y|\G ) - \Ex (Y| \F)) \Ex [ \Ex [(Y - \Ex (Y| \G))| \F] ] \\
&= (\Ex (Y|\G ) - \Ex (Y| \F)) \underbrace{\Ex [  \Ex (Y | \F) - \Ex (Y|G)  ]}_{= \Ex Y - \Ex Y = 0} \\
&=0
\end{align*}$$

Thus, we conclude that
$$\Ex [(Y - \Ex(Y | \F))^2] = \Ex [(Y - \Ex (Y| \G))^2] + \Ex [(\Ex (Y|\G ) - \Ex (Y| \F))^2]$$