# Confusion with conditional expectation and tower property

Tags: probability-theory

I am having trouble understanding how it applies tower property here.
[Conditional Expectation Property with Tower Property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4359987/conditional-expectation-property-with-tower-property)

specifically, below equation:

$[(−(|G))((|G)−(|F))]=[[(−(|G))((|G)−(|F))|F]]$

I understand that $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|G]]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|G]|F]]$ Because $G\subset F$, literally tower property

However, I don't understand why
$\mathbb{E}[Y]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|F]]$

I understand it if $F$ is a random variable, by the law of total expectation. But here F is a sigma-algebra. How is it possible? I am quite confused.

Because, to me, if $F$ is sigma-algebra, by changing $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ to $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|F]]$, aren't we finding the average value of $Y$ only in $F$, like a local average?

Comment: Write out the definition of conditional expectation, then try to prove iterated expectation (it’s essentially trivial)

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[Y]  = \mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{E}[Y| \mathcal{F}]]$ is the definition of Tower Property. If you're confused, maybe you can refer to a standard textbook? Try Probability and Stochastics by Cinlar (it's free online I think)

Comment: @AlanChung I checked the book you mentioned, and, isn't below the Tower Property from the book? (pg 144)
Repeated conditioning: F ⊂ G ⇒ $E_FE_G[X] = E_GE_F[X] = E_F[X]$.
I am still confused if it means $\mathbb{E}[Y]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|F]]$

Comment: Set $Y = E(X\mid \mathcal F)$. Then for all $B\in \mathcal F$, one has $\int_B Y\,dP = \int_B X\,dP$. Taking $B = \Omega$ gives $E(Y) = E(X)$

Comment: @Andrew I really appreciate it! I am sorry but how can we change B to $\Omega$? If $\Omega$ is not be in $F$, when we do $\int_\Omega YdP = \int_\Omega E[X | F] = \int_\Omega X dP$, we cannot change $E[X|F]$ to $X$. Where am I misunderstanding?

Comment: $\Omega \in \mathcal F$, it's part of the definition of a $\sigma$ field

Comment: @Andrew Thank you so much. Is it correct then that E[E[X|F]]=E[X] is because the non-conditioned expectation is over the whole sample space and all sigma algebras always have $\Omega$. In that sense, is it correct that below is true?
1. If two sigma algebras $F\not \subset Z$, $Z\not \subset F$, then: $E[E[X|F]|Z] \neq E[X|Z]$ because $E[X|F]$ cannot be $X$ when integrated over $B\in Z$